# Edit record un tableview using Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am new to core data .I have already performed insert and delete operations but a am not able to get how to perform Update (edit) in it. I am using a Tableview  and on the detailview of it i want to edit my data which will reflect core data.
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass the selected `NSManagedObject` (or your subclass of it) to the DetailViewController and edit its properties.

If you have used NSFetchedResultsController and its delegate methods the main tableView should update when you return from the DetailViewController. If you haven't used them reload the table manually upon return (probably in MainViewControllers viewWillAppear: method).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the examples given in Chapter 7 and 8 in below link:

http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfiphonedev/

Then you only have to handle array in which you fetch records from database and then again write data into database.